# ImageResizer with Private Blobs on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, imageresizer

I have a system providing access to private blobs based on a users login credentials. If they have permission they will be given a SAS Blob url to view document or image stored in Azure.

I want to be able to resize the images, but still maintain the integrity of the short window of access via the SAS.

What is the best approach with ImageResizer? Should I user the AzureReader2 plugin, or should i just use the RemoteReader with the SAS Url?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageResizer would disk cache the resized result images indefinitely, regardless of restrictions on the source file.

You need to implement your authorization logic within the application using `Authorize_Request` or `Config.Current.Pipeline.AuthorizeImage` .

There's no way to pass-through storage authorization unless you disable all caching.